# pthread_cleanup_push handler not working for SIGINT (Ctrl C)

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have a code similar to :

```
myThread()
{
    pthread_cleanup_push(CleanupHandler , NULL)
    while (true)
    {
      /* some code here */
    }
    pthread_cleanup_pop(NULL)

 }

 static void CleanupHandler(void *arg)
 {
   printf("Cleaned\n");
 }
```

But if I terminate my application using ^C (SIGINT), the cleanup handler is not working. Is that expected ? What is the workaround to make the CleanupHandler work at ^C ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is expected, as per man page, `pthread_cleanup_push()` executes in following 3 circumstances:

```
      1) When a thread is canceled
      2) thread terminates using pthread_exit()
      3) when pthread_cleanup_pop()
```

To workaround your problem you can register a signal handler for SIGINT, from that handler use `pthread_exit()` or `pthread_cancel()` to execute your handler. Hope this helps!

Comment: At least on Liunx `pthread_cleanup_pop()` only can be used in direct conjunction with `pthread_cleanup_push()`, that is those to call need to "encapsulate" a common block of code.  So a single call to `pthread_cleanup_pop()` (as proposed to do in a signal handler) won't be possible.

Comment: @alk thanks for the pointer. and yes, pthread_cleanup_pop() has issues and the problem OP has stated, I think for that purpose using `pthread_cancel()` is best.